# Telerik RadListBox Item list how to hide character length and show tooltip?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I would like to hide a length of characters in my Telerik RadListBox ListItems.

Example: (RadListBox Items)

```
Welcome1
Welcome2
Welcome12345678910
```

In my case, if the character length is more than 7, I want to show dot dot.

For example `Welcome1...`

When I mouse over `Welcome1...`, the Tooltip needs to show `Welcome12345678910`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WebForms you could use something like this approach from the example below...

**Markup**

```
<telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="rlb" OnItemDataBound="rlb_ItemDataBound"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void rlb_ItemDataBound(object sender, RadListBoxItemEventArgs e)
{
    const int maxLength = 8;
    if (e.Item.Text.Length <= maxLength) return;
    e.Item.ToolTip = e.Item.Text;
    e.Item.Text = string.Format("{0}...", e.Item.Text.Substring(0, maxLength));
}
```